# apache: add external .conf files dynamically?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, php

I create directories dynamically and for each of them I have to set a custom `open_basedir` directive. I plan to use the apache's `<directory>` directive, combined with `php_admin_value`  calls.

But since the directories are created dynamically, I also need to create these .conf files dynamically as well. Is it possible?

Bonus question: what can I do for it to work with no `service httpd restart`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also need to create these .conf files dynamically as well. Is it possible?

Absolutely, just point to the directory that contains them:

```
Include /path/to/files/*
```

> What can I do for it to work with no service httpd restart?

Only `.htaccess` files are evaluated at runtime, which you should avoid using if you can.

How about `service httpd reload`, though?  A graceful restart will pick up your config changes without losing any requests, since the new process grabs the listener port while letting the old process finish any active requests.

Comment: excellent, you're my hero! I didn't know the reload option...

Comment: May I ask you an additional question? How about the `<directoryMatch regexp>` directive. I think I can also use this because there is a pattern in the dir I'm creating. The only problem is to use backreferences into the directive. Can I do that?

Comment: @Sebas Backreferences would definitely be a problem, as there's no mechanism for that with `<DirectoryMatch>`.  Might be something that could be solved with `mod_rewrite`, though?